# Copy javascript variable to paste the value in a new chrome tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I saw a few examples where user can copy an html text to clipboard. mine is more of dynamic in nature. This is what i am trying to do

```
<button id="" ng-click="outputFolder()">Output Folder</button>

$scope.outputFolder= function () {
        var path = "\\mcsfvwdgemas01\AE";

    };
```

I have this html button. Once ng-click is executed, it has a variable path. I want that variable to be passed on and copied when user clicks the button. Once this is copied, i can open a new tab and paste the path.

I can access the network path this way. Can someone let me know how can i pass the variable path on button click and have it copied.

PS-
If the path is a local folder or a network path, chrome and other browsers donot allow to open due to security restrictions. This is why i am trying this as a workaround –

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly...

```
window.open(path);
```

Should do what you need. I assume this is right as if you open a new tab, there would be nothing to paste into other than the address bar.

Comment: yes, thats wat i tried initially. If the path is a local folder or a network path, chrome and other browsers donot allow to open due to security restrictions. This is why i am trying this as a workaround